# Resources returning null in a resx file

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I am trying to load an image form a resource but its saying its null even though the image is in the resource file.

Declare the image property

```
Image selectedImage = null;
Image emptyImage = null;

ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("SchedurlesImages.resx", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("selected");
Bitmap emptyImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("empty");
```

Here they are showing as null lwhen i step through the debugger why ?
[image]

Comment: This isn't C, no.

Comment: @alk i choose embed resource it is what it is so the tag is reliant.

Comment: You are passing the wrong argument to the ResourceManager constructor.  Don't do it this way, use Project > Properties > Resources.  Press F1 to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared 2 variables or fields:

```
Image selectedImage = null;
Image emptyImage = null;
```

but you are assigning the resources to new local variables (writing a type name in front of a variable makes it a new variable declaration):

```
Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("selected");
Bitmap emptyImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("empty");
```

Remove the type names to use the variable or fields declared previously

```
selectedImage = (Image)rm.GetObject("selected");
emptyImage = (Image)rm.GetObject("empty");
```

---

If the images are in the current project's resources, you can access them with

```
selectedImage = Properties.Resources.selected;
emptyImage = Properties.Resources.empty;
```

Visual Studio creates a code behind file with hard-coded and strongly typed resources.

Comment: it is in the same project but the project is within a solution does that mean i cant use the bottom method as when try to access it that it still not working

Comment: Projects are always in a solution. If the bottom method compiles it does work. Your code does not work because you have two distinct sets of 2 variables. (You have 4 variables).